# C++ program with timers not working

Tags: c++, timer

I made a program in c++ that does certain tasks. The user chooses which ones will be done. First, the program will do them all the user chose, but then it will wait a time specified by the user (in seconds) to do a certain task again; the tasks can have different waiting times.

In my computer it works fine, but I gave the executable to someone and he tells me that it does the task he chose (he just chose task 3 to be done) the first time, but then even after the waiting time ended, it does nothing. I dont know the source of the problem, its the same .exe file I use and in my computer works fine, the behavior should be the same, but for some reason it isn't.

I used msvc 2012. And yes, the user has the Visual C++ Redistributable.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int GetLowestWaitingTime(int* a)

int main()
{
    int WaitingTime[3];
    int TimeForTask[3];
    bool task[3];
    int i;

    cout<<"1=yes 0=no. Press enter after you have typed the chosen number" <<endl;

    for(i = 0; i < 3;i++){
        cout<<"Do you want task " <<i+1 <<" to be performed? ";
        cin >> task[i];

        if(task[i])
        {
            cout<<"Enter the waiting time for task " <<i+1 <<" in seconds: ";
            cin >> TimeForTask[i];
        }else{
            TimeForTask[i] = -1;
        }

        WaitingTime[i] = 0;
    }



    while(1)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(task[i] && WaitingTime[i] == 0)
            {
                //Do task i+1
                WaitingTime[i] = TimeForTask[i];
            }
        }

        SleepTime = GetLowestWaitingTime(WaitingTime);
        SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2); //turn off monitor
        Sleep(SleepTime*1000);

        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if(WaitingTime[i] != -1){
                WaitingTime[i] -= SleepTime;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int GetLowestWaitingTime(int* a)
{
    int l = -2;

    if(a[0] != -1 && ((a[0] < a[1]) || (a[1] == -1))){
        l = a[0];
    }else if(a[1] != -1){
        l = a[1];
    }

    if(l == -2){l = a[2];}else if(l > a[2] && a[2] != -1){l = a[2];}

    return l;
}
```

Comment: You have a while(1) that you don't appear to break out of. Does SendMessage() do that? Otherwise, you'll remain stuck in that while loop forever.

Comment: It could be hanging on that SendMessage.  I don't think it really does what you intend it to do.

Answer (score 0):

you set WaitingTime to 0 for each index, but your sentinel is -1, so you'll always get 0 for SleepTime.

Try the following for your while loop:

```
while(1)
{
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if(task[i] && WaitingTime[i] == 0)
        {
            //Do task i+1
            WaitingTime[i] = TimeForTask[i];
        }
        else
        {
            WaitingTime[i] = -1;
        }
    }

    SleepTime = GetLowestWaitingTime(WaitingTime);
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2); //turn off monitor
    Sleep(SleepTime*1000);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(WaitingTime[i] != -1){
            WaitingTime[i] -= SleepTime;
        }
    }
}
```